# Navigating forward/backward in Microsoft Word?

Tags: ms-office

I have a Word document with internal links (i.e. a link will jump to anchor in the same document). When I click on one of these links, it jumps to that location, as it is supposed to.

How can I get back to the location I was at before I clicked the link? I can't find a back or forward button anywhere.

Also, if I'm in **Outline** view, it changes the view to **Print Layout**. Is there any way to have the back button also switch the view back to how it was originally? In other words, I'm looking for a way to undo the link click.

I'm using Microsoft Word 2011 (for Mac).

Answer (score 2):

Use Shift + F5 to return to the last edit location in the document

Answer (score -1):

The answer for Windows is to press Alt + LEFT ARROW. Perhaps the Mac has something very similar to the Alt button?

Comment: The Alt button is the Option/Alt button on a Mac.  Your answer, though, has to do with Windows, not Mac.

Comment: Have you tried it on the Mac?